# Converting between linear and 2dimensional arrays

Tags: arrays, 2d

I am trying to convert between linear and 2 dimensional arrays. The formula from 2d to linear is pretty straightforward, but I have been having trouble with undoing it (get the 2d position from the linear position). Is it possible? How?

For example, let's say I have the array { A, B, C, D, E, F } and I know the 2d array for it is: {{ A, B, C }, { D, E, F }} or

```
[A, B, C]
[D, E, F]
```

so that F position is given by (1, 2). How would I know the position for the other elements in an algorithmic way?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @guido Edited the question, trying to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Assuming the array is rectangular, like this:

```
###
###
###
###
```

not irregular, like this:

```
#######
#####
##########
```

(which is possible in some languages such as Java), then you can use integer division and modulus operations:

```
row = i / numColumns
col = i % numColumns
```

This is assuming zero-based arrays, and the convention that the array is first divided into rows, and then each row is divided into cells.